# Why is 'João' coming out as 'Jo\u00e3o'?

Tags: mysql, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I have this column in my database table:

```
`data` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL
```

Names like 'João' are inserted. But they're showing up as `Jo\u00e3o`. E.g.:

```
{"4":"jo\u00e3o da silva"}
```

I tried changing the character set and the collation, but it didn't seem to help. What can I do in order to fix it?

My database "character set" settings:

[image: MySQL character set settings]

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8b30bcd68456114af4de3c5c5361da8 Maybe this is your client software issue?

Comment: *But they're showing up as 'Jo\u00e3o'.* Query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and provide the output.

Comment: @Akina https://i.imgur.com/qSlXblX.png Image added to main post.

Comment: @Akina are you referring to the app I use to see and modify the database? I have both DBeaver and phpMyAdmin, but the results are the same.

Comment: *are you referring to the app I use to see and modify the database?* Yes. Query via CLI... PS. Settings are correct. The transformation is performed after MySQL returns the output.

Comment: @Akina do you have any clue what's wrong them? I don't think it is the software. Maybe it's the plugin I'm using to input data in the database. But what should I look for in order to fix it, you think? Other fields from other tables, that contain special characters, work just fine.

Comment: [That is a valid JSON escape sequence](https://3v4l.org/p59VQ), it has been correctly encoded. While JSON documents must be UTF-8 it is usually preferable to escape high-order UTF codepoints to ensure that they do not get mangled/mishandled in transit. While I would personally advise leaving the encoding alone, if you're certain that your data exchanges are safe, then you can feed the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Sammitch that makes much more sense now! I guess I'll just end up using a tool to unescape those values, but now I'm curious. How can I tell if my data exchanges are safe, and where should I look in my plugin/app's code to feed that into json_encode()? Thank ya!

Comment: @Sammitch The column datatype is MEDIUMTEXT, not JSON. So the value datatype is TEXT until this data leaves MySQL and arrives to another software. You demonstrate that the problem may be PHP-side problem.

Comment: *I don't think it is the software.* @Sammitch's comment shows that you may think incorrectly.

Comment: @Hilas you don't have to unescape them, when the JSON is decoded it will happen automatically. As I said/demonstrated before this is perfectly valid JSON. I recommend _not_ using unescaped unicode in your JSON because you don't have to worry about making sure your data exchanges are safe. That's why it is the default. You don't have an actual problem, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Sammitch I see. Sometimes, I have to copy data from that column and throw it in Excel. It would be useful if I could read the data 'unescaped'. Do you have any recommendations to make that process easier?

Comment: You would simply need to apply the decoding correctly. In a perfect world you'd be browsing the data via your application which would transparently apply `json_decode()` or equivalent. But if you're querying directly you can apply mySQL's JSON functions, eg: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vv5Nh5T2rtvc6uxPs1jehk/1

Comment: That said, storing serialized data in a relational DB is only really a good idea if you only ever deal with that data in its entirety. Eg: Read/write the entire thing. Once you need to start querying _within_ that data you should look at moving it to a properly normalized table structure. The JSON functions are a "nice to have" for the odd occasion you want to pick out bits of data in isolation, but generally become a performance/scaling pain point the more you rely on them in your application.

Comment: Never trust your screen. I'm not sure if you did, but save **directly** data to a file and open it in an editor. Output functions (on different layers) often mangle data (when they think some other layers cannot display it correctly), and that make difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `\u00e3` is not generated by MySQL.  It is, however, optionally generated by PHP's `json_encode()`.  Be sure to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in the second argument to that function.

Meanwhile, those codes are properly interpreted by web browsers, so you won't notice issues there.  And reading and writing from and to a database won't change them.  But note that any backslash needs to be escaped when `INSERTing` into a database table.

For use in MySQL tables, I prefer to have the connection and server settings consistently set at `utf8mb4` so that Unicode stuff simply comes and goes without conversion.

I agree with "never trust your screen".  About the only way to see what is actually stored in the database is to use `SELECT HEX(col)...` For `ã`:

```
UTF-8 (utf8mb4): Hex: C3A3 
latin1:          Hex:  E3
```

But, for `\u00e3`, the hex would be 5C7530306533

In PHP, there is `bin2hex()`.